# Combining two strings into one variable inserts weird "\" chars when I try to run it in a subproccess

Tags: python, bash

I have the following python function:

```
def run(self):
    print(f"exec {self.o}")
    a = f"""cd /usr/share/applications && cat {self.o}.desktop | grep "^Exec*" |""" 
    b = """awk '{gsub("Exec=", "");print}'"""
    a2 = (''.join(a.splitlines()))
    b2 = (''.join(b.splitlines()))
    o2 = (a2 + b2)
    print(o2)
    subprocess.run(o2)
```

I had to concatenate two weird variables together into one because `"""` did not like to combine the awk with the rest of it. If I print it for testing it prints out fine (note: the alacrity is my `self.o` variable).

```
cd /usr/share/applications && cat Alacritty.desktop | grep "^Exec*" |awk '{gsub("Exec=", "");print}'
```

which is perfectly runnable at the shell. But if I try to run it in `subprocess.run` in the error it shows the string with weird backslash `\` chars everywhere in the awk section.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd /usr/share/applications && cat Alacritty.desktop | grep "^Exec*" |awk \'{gsub("Exec=", "");print}\''
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Why are you using `a.splitlines()` and `b.splitlines()`? Neither string has any newlines in it.

Comment: You need the `shell=True` option to `subprocess.run()` to make it parse shell operations like `&&` and `|`

Comment: Why are you using shell commands for this? You can do all of this with built-in Python functions.

Comment: The backslashes aren't actually present in your string. They're how Python is *printing* the file name. It surrounds the whole thing with single quotes and escapes the inner single quotes with backslashes to create what looks like a string literal. This lets you copy and paste the whole thing into your program verbatim in case that helps when troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks @Barmar that fixed it.